# Getting 'Did not match' Logs after Migrating Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.x

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, migration

I have followed the below documentation for migration from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.x.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Right now my project is up and running but getting so many `Did not match` logs. A few of them are shown below.

Can anyone please tell me what this indicates. Also Am I doing anything wrong?

```
        :
        :
        :
        :
       ThymeleafAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode' (OnClassCondition)

       TomcatMetricsAutoConfiguration#contextCapturingReactiveTomcatCustomizer:
          Did not match:
             - not a reactive web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) did not find property 'proxy-target-class' (OnPropertyCondition)

       UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' authenticationManagerBean (OnBeanCondition)
          Matched:
             - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

       WavefrontMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.wavefront.WavefrontMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

       WebClientAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

       WebFluxAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

       WebFluxEndpointManagementContextConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler' (OnClassCondition)

       WebFluxMetricsAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - not a reactive web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

       WebFluxSecurityConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - not a reactive web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)
          Matched:
             - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity', 'org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.ResourceChainCustomizerConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain did not find class org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator (OnEnabledResourceChainCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver' beanNameViewResolver (OnBeanCondition)

       WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#localeResolver:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.locale) did not find property 'locale' (OnPropertyCondition)

       WebServicesAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

       WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

       WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - not a reactive web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)
          Matched:
             - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

       WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.JettyWebSocketConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer' (OnClassCondition)

       WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.UndertowWebSocketConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap' (OnClassCondition)

       XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
          Did not match:
             - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper (OnBeanCondition)
          Matched:
             - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)


    Exclusions:
    -----------

        None


    Unconditional classes:
    ----------------------

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.management.HeapDumpWebEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.bus.BusPropertiesAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.scheduling.ScheduledTasksEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.logging.LogFileWebEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.commons.httpclient.HttpClientConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.env.EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.ShutdownEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.trace.http.HttpTraceEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.logging.LoggersEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.client.CommonsClientAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.beans.BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionsReportEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.mappings.MappingsEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.management.ThreadDumpEndpointAutoConfiguration

        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
```

### UPDATE 1

My **spring-logback.xml** is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Once you’re done with the migration, please make sure to remove this module from your project’s dependencies. [ref](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#before-you-start)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I have removed that as well....still the same

Comment: ```debug=true``` in your ```application.properties``` ?

Comment: @DirkDeyne I have added that but still the same

Comment: Alex, just to be clear if you use ```debug=true``` in your application.properties spring-boot will print all _Conditional classes_  and  _Unconditional classes_  so if you don't want that, debug should be set to false!

Comment: @DirkDeyne I am using spring-logback.xml...where consoleappender is INFO level  `<appender name="STDOUT"
  class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
   <level>INFO</level>
  </filter>
  <encoder>
   <Pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level
    %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</Pattern>
  </encoder>
 </appender>`

Comment: if I use logback with spring-boot I use ```logback.xml``` not ```spring-logback.xml``` ... [Configure Logback for Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging)
Do you get alot of DEBUG outputs when you start your application? If yes then you have somewhere set the logging-level to DEBUG...

Comment: @DirkDeyne can you check my Update 1. I have shown my srping-logback.xml file. Even I am getting the same `Did not find match` logs when I set the root level is made info. I also added `logging.level.root= INFO ` and `debug= false` to my property file as well

Comment: Alex try this:
 - add to your application.properties: ```logging.config=classpath:spring-logback.xml```
 -  change your spring-logback.xml to

     ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration><include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/><logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/></configuration>```


ref: [spring-boot: howto-configure-logback-for-logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging)

Comment: @DirkDeyne Thanks for the continuous support.....I did that still it was showing the same logs

Comment: sorry, I couldn't help.

Comment: I cannot for now, this evening i can around @1900CET.

Comment: sure,..... ... ...